# No menu in Ubuntu bitcoin-qt

Tags: bitcoin-core, ubuntu, bitcoin-qt-setup

When I run bitcoin-qt on Ubuntu 12.04, I see this:

[image]

As you can see, there is no menu on the top menu bar.  There is the "beginning" of a menu with the word "Bitcoin" but there are no "File", "Settings", or "Help" menu titles.  Clicking on the word "Bitcoin" in the menu bar does nothing.

According to [this](http://computriks.com/en/bitcoin-encrypt-wallet) it seems there should be a menu.

How do I get the menu to work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens with many Ubuntu Apps. The simplest solution is to tap <kbd>Alt</kbd> any type the name of the menu item you wish to find.

[image]

Alternatively, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd>, log in, type `DISPLAY=:0.0 unity --replace` hit Enter, and then do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd>. The menu bars and the windowing system will reload.

Answer (score 2):

This solved it on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove appmenu-qt5
```

and the menu was visible when bitcoin-qt (bitcoin-0.13.0rc1, compiled from source) restarted.